# ligações entre tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Inscricao WHERE al_id = ".$_GET['idc'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Aluno WHERE al_id = ".$_GET['idc'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM EncarregadoDeEducacao WHERE ee_id = ee_id.inscricao where al_id = ".$_GET['idc'];
```

tabelas :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Inscricao` (
 `insc_id`                      int(4) unsigned Not Null AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `al_id`                        int(4) Not Null DEFAULT '0',
 `ee_id`                        int(4) Not Null DEFAULT '0',
 `obs_desc`                     varchar(250)    Not Null DEFAULT 'Sem observacoes',
 `prof_nome`                    varchar(50) Not Null DEFAULT '',
 `insc_data`                    DATE Not Null DEFAULT '00-00-0000', 
  PRIMARY KEY (`insc_id`)
) ENGINE=myisam DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Aluno` (
 `al_id`                        int(4) unsigned Not Null AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `al_nome`                      varchar(50) Not Null DEFAULT '',
 `al_idade`                     int(2)  Not Null DEFAULT '0',   
 `al_data`                      DATE Not Null DEFAULT '00-00-0000', 
 `al_morada`                    varchar(80) Not Null DEFAULT '',    
 `al_escolaridade`              int(2)  Not Null DEFAULT '0',   
 `al_nomepai`                   varchar(50) Not Null DEFAULT '',    
 `al_nomemae`                   varchar(50) Not Null DEFAULT '',    
 `al_nomeensino`                varchar(50) Not Null DEFAULT '',    
 `al_localensino`               varchar(80) Not Null DEFAULT '',    
 `al_img`                       varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `ocupacao`                     varchar(250)    Not Null DEFAULT 'sem ocupacao de tempos livres',
 `tra_simnao`                   varchar(250)    Not Null DEFAULT 'nao',
 `tra_desc`                     varchar(250)    Not Null DEFAULT 'Sem Transporte',
  PRIMARY KEY (`al_id`)
) ENGINE=myisam DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `EncarregadoDeEducacao` (
 `ee_id`                        int(4) unsigned Not Null AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ee_nome`                      varchar(50) Not Null DEFAULT '',    
 `ee_parentesco`                varchar(10) Not Null DEFAULT '',    
 `ee_localtrab`                 varchar(80) Not Null DEFAULT '',    
 `ee_telemovel`                 int(9)  Not Null DEFAULT 0,
 `ee_telefone`                  int(9)  Not Null DEFAULT 0,
 `ee_urgencia`                  int(9)  Not Null DEFAULT 0,
 `ee_email`                     varchar(50) Not Null DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ee_id`)
) ENGINE=myisam DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Preciso de seleccionar dados das 3 tabelas para listar os dados da inscriçao completa do aluno ( dados das 3 tabelas ) por exemplo inscriçao 1 com aluno 2 encarregado de educaçao 5 e os respetivos dados de cada um dos 3.

se tentar colocar em 3 select sei que da erro queria saber como faço para fazer o que quero sem erro, obrigado.

Comment: helder tente fornecer mais dados a sua pergunta. Como são as tabelas que está a usar? O que precisa de fazer? Assim não está clara a sua questão.

Comment: Além disso a última string SQL não deve funcionar assim...

Comment: As tabelas `Inscricao`, `Aluno` e `EncarregadoDeEducacao` possuem a mesma estrutura? A princípio, pode-se usar `UNION` para juntar as três *queries* em uma, mas teria-se que preencher as colunas inexistentes com `NULL` caso as estruturas das tabelas sejam diferentes (não sei se o SQL faz isso automaticamente ou não). P.S. Seu `idc` é único entre as três tabelas? Se sim, como você garante isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que juntar as chaves com a tabela baseado no que você tem na tabela de Inscrições:

```
    select *
    from Inscricoes i
    inner join Aluno a on a.al_id = i.al_id
    inner join EncarregadoDeEducacao e on e.ee_id = i.ee_id
    WHERE a.al_id = SEU_PARAMETRO
    /*
        Aqui você pode continuar o where, order by e etc...
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

obrigada pela ajuda, 
quando vi a sua resposta já tinha feito assim :

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Inscricao, Aluno, EncarregadoDeEducacao WHERE Inscricao.al_id = Aluno.al_id AND EncarregadoDeEducacao.ee_id = Inscricao.ee_id AND Inscricao.al_id = ".$_GET['idc'];
```

penso que ambos estejam be